# Are these examples of functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$? Or are those examples not well-defined?

Tags: functions, logic

I have three examples of candidate functions here, and I'm wondering if they really are functions, or if they are not well-defined.

The function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ where $f(n)$ is the smallest prime $p>n$ such that $p+2$ is also prime. If such $p$ doesn't exist, then $f(n)=1$.

The function $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ where $g(n)=1$ if there exist a prime $p$ such that $$100^{100^n}<p<100^{100^n}+10^{10}.$$
If such $p$ doesn't exist, then $f(n)=2$.

The function $h:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ where $h(n)=1$ if Riemann hypothesis is true, and otherwise $h(n)=10$.

Comment: The last one is not well-defined if $0$ is not a natural number :)

Comment: @Yoni: Which never happens, so it's fine. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. These are well-defined functions. Just don't confuse between a function being well-defined, and us being able to evaluate its output for every given number (or any number, for that matter).

Comment: So it is perfecly valid in mathematics to assign suck kind of rule ?

Comment: As long as the output is *unique*, it's well-defined. Since we can prove that the Riemann Hypothesis is either true or false (in a fixed universe of mathematics), but not both and not neither, it's well-defined.

Comment: The other functions really just amount of a tedious computation which is "easily done" by a theoretical machine (e.g. Turing machine) which is not bounded by physical time or resources.

Comment: Actually $f$ is similar to $h$ in that respect. We'll need to know whether the twin prime conjecture is true or not before we can write down the "easy" computation that realizes it.

Comment: @Henning: Yes, you're right. One can always ask an $\Sigma^0_2$-oracle. :-)

Comment: You must reflect on [Constructive Mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/) : "it is perfecly valid in mathematics to assign suck kind of rule", but in which "meaningful" contexts make sense to introduce such kind of "functions" ? I'm not a *constructivist*, but I "like" to consider also the constructivist point of view.